# How to route to a "subcomponent" in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have a file structure like this:

```
app/
└── blog/
    └── posts/
        └── python-coding/
```

I have a route in my header that goes to blog, I am trying to make a routerLink that goes to python-coding post. posts is just and organizational directory, doesn't have any components.

I don't understand how to make the route on the blog page to python-coding work.

```
// src/app/app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { PythonCoding } from './blog/posts/python-coding/python-coding.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
    { path: 'posts/python-coding', component: PythonCoding },
];
```

I noticed that when I had blog/posts/python-coding, when I hovered in browser it was blog/blog/... so removed blog from path.

```
// src/app/app.component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
}
```

app has RouterOutlet imported, and uses it in template:

```
<!-- src/app/app.component.html -->
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The header has a working link to the blog, but I want the blog to have a working link to the python-code subpage:

```
<!-- src/app/blog/blog.component.html -->
<h1>Blog Posts:</h1>
<a routerLink="posts/python-coding">Python Coding</a>
```

However that link doesn't go to that page when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may go with this [LINK](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes) this will help you the kind of routing you want to achive

Comment: This has gotten me further, this is the correct direction. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think router-outlet is sufficient to solve the problem. Lets say I have a post and I have the blog home. When I want to show the post it has to unserve the blog home and serve the post, which I think requires JS. What approach could I take to do this. I have been trying to make a service with an injection decorator, but its not going well.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have set up your routing correctly, but the issue might be related to the way you are defining the router link in your `blog.component.html`. Since the `blog` component is already at the `/blog` route, you should not repeat `blog` in the `routerLink`.

Try modifying your link to the Python Coding post like this:

```
    <!-- src/app/blog/blog.component.html -->
<h1>Blog Posts:</h1>
<a routerLink="python-coding">Python Coding</a>
```

This should correctly navigate to the `/blog/posts/python-coding` route when clicked.

Additionally, ensure that your `PythonCoding` component is correctly implemented and accessible at the `/posts/python-coding` route. If there are any issues with the component implementation or route configuration, that could also prevent the navigation from working as expected.